# How to list down all the processes with User interface only on Unix and Windows?

Tags: windows, user-interface, unix, process, electron

I am building one desktop application using electron js + Node Js. This will be an desktop usages monitoring application.

My target is to list down all the open applications names and their process IDs if possible which are having user interface. e.g. Notepad, MS Office applications, Visual studio etc.

Ultimately I need to control which applications can be opened on the desktop and which can be blocked from usages. I can not have a list of all the applications in the world and then check those one by one via process list. So as a work around, If I get the list of all the open applications with UI associated with it, I can at least show the user if this application is allowed to use or not.

Platform I am using is Unix/Windows/MacOS.

If there is no straight forward solution to it, can we think of something like using OpenCV and understand image by some algo to check the open application windows? Because any way I am interested to find the application on the top of all i.e. active.

Is there any way to identify such processes/applications?

Comment: As I understand your question, the problem you want to solve is "*I am interested to find the application on the top of all i.e. active.*". Please [edit] your question and add more details about this: What do you want to achieve? What do you want to do with this information? What exactly do you need? Process ID? Program name? Window handle? ...

Comment: If you are asking for tools, this is off topic. If you want to write a program, specify a language...

Comment: you'll have to write platform-specific code... or find a library that already did it. enumerating displayed windows is a single API call or a handful for pretty much all operating systems. there's no need to use a _specific_ version of a _computer vision library_.

Comment: Question is updated as per suggestion.